# Unix Executable File To Text File

Tags: executable

Is there a way to change a text file to a unix executable file without terminal? I'm using a school laptop that is a MAC and it doesn't allow me to use terminal. Im trying to change a text file or a .txt file into a unix executable file. I need to do this so I can run an .app. I need to or I cannot open the .app which is crucial to me. I have the application, I just can't simply run it because the file that uses the terminal to open the app is a .txt file. My friend transferred this file to me and it works for him. But I look where it shows a unix executable file for him and mine is just a text file that uses text edit. Thanks!

Comment: You're not allowed to use the Terminal?  Wow.

Comment: When your question has been put on hold, please don’t go and just post the same question again.  (1) You should clean up your original question so it is clear and complete, responding to comments.  (2) Why are you still asking this question?  It looks like you got an answer to the first one.  Is there something wrong with that?  If so, you should say so, rather than make people answer the same question for you again.

Comment: I have a mac. The other people were telling me things for a pc.

Answer (score 0):

Most dm support editing 'executable' flag via 'preferences'. So try Right Mouse Click on it, then 'preferences', search by tabs for something like 'Is executable?' and check if needed.

Comment: i have a mac there is no preferences tab